# Do we have to mention port to communicate between containers inside a same pod - kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, port, devops

Do we have to mention port to communicate between containers inside a same pod  - kubernetes

Comment: Multiple containers within the same pod? Then the answer is yes....so everyone should be able to communicate with each other with `http://localhost:port`

Comment: You always need to specify a port, regardless of whether you're dealing with services in the same pod or services located in different countries. Without specifying the port, the target system cannot determine to which service you're trying to connect.